# How to connect to SVN server in Java and more?

Tags: java, svn, uml

I have a project where I have to pull data or code from SVN and create a sequence/class/UML diagram based on code/data retrieved from SVN.

My questions are:

1. How to connect to SVN server from java?
2. Is there any java libraries that can take a class method and generate a sequence diagram?
3. Is there any java library that can generate a UML 2.0 complaint diagram from class file?

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: questions should be on a single topic

Comment: I thought of doing that...but seeing it's part of the same project, I decided to put them all together. Single point of reference.

Comment: a single point of reference only makes sense for you, not the thousands of other SO users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your SVN Java-API question: [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) is really handy.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well the need is to reverse engineer sequence and class diagram from existing code which is currently shared by the team on SVN.

You can not do reverse programmatically using a method because this is a lot more complex than just a method. You certainly have hundred of methods or more called for a basic reverse engineering option.
The step to reverse engineer a Java code into an UML diagram is to:
First map your code to a UML model: You can do it but just a drag and drop or by reversing the full project and then creating UML views from your model

Once the UML project has been created you can share it directly on SVN with the other users if they use Eclipse, if they don't use Eclipse then you can export image of your sequence diagram using the image export option and copy this image inside your team project for documentation purposes.

Comment: Thanks....but that is an Eclipse Plugin, is there any library that I can use that can do this too? I am told to create the UMLs, class diagrams, etc. and display it on a web page, i.e. I'm doing this through a web application.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/svn4j/

Comment: Where can I download SVN4J? I don't find any place of download.